# VBA MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 Web Request with Kerberos Authentication

Tags: vba, kerberos

I have a VBA script using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` for web requests.

Is there any way to get Kerberos authentication working with these requests? The requests are always coming back 401 Unauthorized when I try with it.

I've confirmed my web app works with Kerberos authentication in Chrome/Edge, so that's set up properly.

I know it can work with `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` by using `SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)`, but we need to use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` for other reasons.

For reference, here's the basic code. The actual URL and body are correct. If I disable Kerberos on the URL side this works fine.

```
Dim http As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Call http.Open("POST", url, False)
Call http.send(body) ' <=== 401 Unauthorized returned
```

Comment: Always helps to show the specific code you tried.